# Chrome browser always hangs and can not open Apex Developer Guide

Tags: developer

This situation has been happening for a while.

When using chrome browser to connect Apex Developer Guide, the browser always hangs until an error message appears.

The same situation does not happen if I change to use Edge browser.

I've tested with incognito mode so that addons could not be the causes of the issue.

[image]

Does anyone have the same chrome browser issue? and solution?

Answer (score 1):

Issue seems to be specific with chrome installed on your machine,  And I do not see any issues while using the chrome browser.

Check more details on troubleshooting steps for Chrome [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312846&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1).

Thanks